# Convert SQL Distinct, Count & GroupBy to a Linq query with Navigation

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query in LINQ, where `query` is a pre-defined IQueryable from the table `LeadSales`...

```
var results = from q in query
    select new LeadBuyersByStateItem {
        ContactID = q.SoldToContactID,
        FirstName = q.Contact.FirstName,
        LastName = q.Contact.LastName
     };
```

It works fine, but I need to adjust it a little.  I also have this in SQL:

```
SELECT
    SoldToContactID, 
    COUNT (SoldToContactID) AS Count
FROM
    LeadSales
GROUP BY 
    SoldToContactID
```

Which returns this dataset, as expected:

[image]

So now, I need to convert the LINQ query to have the GROUP BY, and include the Count, and of course keep the navigation so I can get to FirstName and LastName.

I'm having trouble with the LINQ syntax...

```
var results = from q in query
    group q by q.SoldToContactID into g
    select new LeadBuyersByStateItem {
        ContactID = ?.SoldToContactID,
        FirstName = ?.Contact.FirstName,
        LastName = ?.Contact.LastName
        ContactCount = ????
     };
```

And just FYI...

```
public class LeadBuyersByStateItem
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ContactCount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var results = from q in query
    group q by new {q.SoldToContactID,
                    FirstName=q.Contact.FirstName,
                    LastName=q.Contact.LastName} into g
    select new LeadBuyersByStateItem {
        ContactID = g.Key.SoldToContactID,
        FirstName = g.Key.FirstName,
        LastName = g.Key.LastName,
        ContactCount = g.Count()
     };
```

You need to group by several columns using an anonymous type

Comment: Getting close.  It errors out on g.Key.Contact because Contact is not in the group by.

Comment: I saw it now, i think I fixed ;)

Comment: Sweet.  I'll test.  (missing a comma after g.Key.LastName, but no big deal)

Comment: That's it!  Thanks :-)